# How to view translated document from

Tags: python, google-translate

I am translating a document using google cloud translation api. See [here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/translate-documents?hl=en#translate_v3beta1_translate_document-python).

In the documentation, it says to "To view translated document, write `response.document_translation.byte_stream_outputs` to file". But I don't see how to do that? Does anyone know how to?

Edit --
Simple code such as

```
with open('translated_file.txt', 'wb') as f:     
    f.write(response.document_translation.byte_stream_outputs)
```

gives the following error "a bytes-like object is required, not 'Repeated'".

In particular, response.document_translation.byte_stream_outputs has the type marshal.collections.repeated.Repeated

Comment: it's probably same as writing any other content to a file. have you tried `with open('translated_file.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.document_translation.byte_stream_outputs)`

Comment: @chickitychinachinesechicken doesn't work, see my edit.

Comment: maybe check what public methods the object has: `dir(response.document_translation.byte_stream_outputs)`, look for something like a `_str()` or some method to return value as string or other writeable datatype.

Answer (score 0):

With the following code, you can output binary file.

```
with open('translated_file.txt', 'wb') as f:     
   f.write(response.document_translation.byte_stream_outputs[0])
```